# Pulling large number of tweets by id

Tags: twitter, tweets

I have a list of 5500 tweet ids.  For each tweet id, I'm downloading the associated tweet text.  The ids are non-sequential and from many different users.

The only API option I see for pulling a specific tweet is [GET statuses/show/:id](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/show/%3aid).

That gives only a tweet at a time.  With rate limiting of 350 API calls / hr, that means ~16 hrs to download the data.

Is there an API call or better technique that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. I'm afraid none. There's no way to bypass twitters 350 API Calls per hour for authenticated users.

Answer (score 3):

You can buy tweets from [GNIP](http://gnip.com/).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understood, Twitter API has an end point to fetch up to 100 tweets per request. You can find the details at: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/lookup
I use tweepy's statuses_lookup method: http://tweepy.readthedocs.org/en/v3.1.0/api.html#timeline-methods So, you can retrieve tweets much faster than requesting one tweet at a time.

Comment: Don't think this endpoint existed when the original question was written, but great to know.  Thanks!

Comment: I agree with you, it should be relatively a new feature.